# How is $\lambda$ tuning parameter in lasso logistic regression generated

Tags: lasso

I know `glmnet(x,y)` generates $\lambda$ but I am very curious to know the actual formula that is behind this, generating $\lambda$.

Comment: Are you talking about the function `glmnet` in the *R* package `glmnet`?

Comment: @Glen_b  yes library(glmnet) in R

Comment: I discovered one thing I had missed before: [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/glmnet/docs/glmnet) (scroll down to `lambda.min.ratio`) it says that the largest value of $\lambda$, `lambda.max` is *the (data derived) entry value (i.e. the smallest value for which all coefficients are zero)*. Once `lambda.max` is given, obtaining the rest of the $\lambda$ sequence should be pretty simple. The question remains, how is `lambda.max` calculated?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same question and also ran into confusion in the F90 code in the glmnet package. In the end I took some code from the [quadrupen](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadrupen/index.html) package (at the end of quadrupen.R) and modified it for my purposes. I can confirm that the maximum lambda value produces all zero coefficients in glmnet with alpha=1. I'd love to hear better answers to this question or an implementation of the glmnet fortran version in R --- at least to help with teaching and learning.

```
### from quadrupen
## GENERATE A GRID OF PENALTIES IF NONE HAVE BEEN PROVIDED
get.lambda.l1  <-  function(xs,y,nlambda,min.ratio) {
  ##xs     <-  as(x, "dgCMatrix")
  ## currently not robust to missing values in xs or y
  ybar <- mean(y,na.rm=TRUE)
  xbar <- colMeans(xs,na.rm=TRUE)
  x      <-  list(Xi = xs@i, Xj = xs@p, Xnp = diff(xs@p), Xx = xs@x)
  xty    <-  drop(crossprod(y-ybar,scale(xs,xbar,FALSE)))
  lmax  <-  max(abs(xty))
  return(10^seq(log10(lmax), log10(min.ratio*lmax), len=nlambda))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf), it seems that cross-validation is used on a self-generated sequence for lambda.

This results in the `lambda.min` being the lambda value in the sequence which produces the smallest `cvm` (mean cross-validated error) and `lambda.1se` being the largest lambda in the sequence such that error is within 1 standard error of the minimum.

There is some discussion and illustration in section 6 of the [JStatSoft article](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v33/i01/)

Comment: Your answer addresses a different question than the one being asked. The question of interest is *how the sequence of lambda is generated* by the function `glmnet` in the `glmnet` package in `R`. I have been wondering about this question and checked the code behind the `glmnet` function, but ultimately faced some `Fortran` code (since the `glmnet` package is not entirely coded in `R`) which I had trouble with... I was unable to find the answer in the documentation nor in the JStatSoft article.